# How to remove text after DOT [.]

Tags: java, selenium

I need to enter the string after removing the .jpg extension onwards[ i.e. 01_US_CAN_141.jpg] i.e. the required string is -‘e 01_US_CAN_141’

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `split()` on this String:

```
String[] name = "01_US_CAN_141.jpg".split(".");
name[0] //01_US_CAN_141
```

If your String has more than one dots, then you can use something like this:

```
String name = "01_US_CAN_141.jpg".substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expression like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "01_US_CAN_141.jpg";
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\.\\w{3}$", ""));
}
```

The reason is that dot might not just separate file extension from file name. File name itself might also contain dots.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there is only one point in string. So you can use this;

```
String firstPart = "01_US_CAN_141.jpg".split("[.]")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to remove the part *`.jpg`* from *`01_US_CAN_141.jpg`*

- Using `split()` and *index*:

  ```
  String text = "01_US_CAN_141.jpg";
  String[] texts = text.split(".");
  System.out.println(texts[0]);
  ```